# Javascript - Find all implicitly declared variables in directory?

Tags: javascript

I have 100+ js files in a directory in atom editor. In chrome console I get errors about many variables not being defined (only the ones I interact with on the page are the ones that show they are undefined), but the error goes away and that portion of js works when I add the `var/const/let` keyword before those variables.

I now understand that they are `implicitly implied variables` because throughout the files, some are defined like this (strict mode is on):

```
foo = bar; // This is an implicitly implied variable
var foo = bar; // This fixes the issue
```

So the solution is to add `var/const/let` before those variables, but I am wondering if there is any way to scan the directory of files to point out the implicitly implied variables so I can add `var/const/let` in front of them?

It is taking very long to navigate through all the files manually scanning for those variables to fix up or navigate the app and wait for the error to show up to fix it one by one.

Any quick solution for this (without disabling strict mode)?

Comment: use a linter like jshint/jslint/eslint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a linter for the directory, which will browse through all the files and raise warnings.

[JSHint](http://jshint.com/install/) is a popular one, and it's pretty easy to get going with [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jshint) from the command line, or you can install it into your code editor like [Atom](https://atom.io/packages/atom-jshint) or [Sublime](https://github.com/uipoet/sublime-jshint).

The CLI version will be more powerful, you can specify a directory for it to scan, and recursively scan all children. In your code editor, you'll usually only get warnings for the file you currently have open.

Comment: Thank you, will look more into it! :)